# how to install scala ide

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

hi I am trying to install scala IDE I watched [this](http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/gettingstarted.html) Getting Started tutorial when I copy

http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/helium/e38/scala211/stable/site

this location from [here](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html) into eclipse it gives me error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Scala Search 0.2.2.v-2_11-201407232051-fc76d40 (org.scala.tools.eclipse.search.feature.feature.group 0.2.2.v-2_11-201407232051-fc76d40)
```

I am using

- ubuntu LTS12.04 OS
- eclipse indigo
- scala-2.11.1

please help

Comment: Try with IntellijIDEA.

Comment: how ?? please guide me

Comment: Download that IDE and install Scala plugin.

Comment: but i want to use eclipse only

Answer (score 3):

You can download the whole package bundle that contains eclipse and is tested and working well from the following location

http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html